# Openlayers source.once(change) does not update my polygons

Tags: javascript, kml, openlayers-3

I'm trying to have some coordinates giving through KML to project some polygons onto a map, and while the polygons is projected perfectly, no matter what I change in the kml nothing happens and I have to refresh the page anyways.

Here's my code :

```
var polygons;

map = new ol.Map({
    render: 'canvas',
    layers: [raster, vector],
    target: 'map',
    interactions: interactions,
    view: view
});

var styling = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: [225, 85, 83, .4]
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: [135, 13, 39, .8],
      width: 2,
      lineCap: 'round'
    })
});

function testpolygons() {
    var new_source = new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'pages/Coordinates.php',
        format: new ol.format.KML({
                extractStyles: false,
                extractAttributes: false
            })
    });

    var new_layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new_source,
        style: styling
    });

    map.addLayer(new_layer);

    new_source.once('change', function() {
        if (polygons) {
            map.removeLayer(polygons);
        }
        polygons= new_layer;
    });
    if (polygons!== undefined)
        polygons.setVisible(false);
}

testpolygons();
```

And this is what's my coordinates page has :

```
test 1 irrelativeToGround 10.416666666667,40.375 10.583333333333,40.891666666667 10.25,40.891666666667 10.25,40.058333333333 10.583333333333,40.058333333333 test 1 irrelativeToGround 10.25,40.391666666667 10.145833333333,40.491666666667 10.4,40.575 10.504166666667,40.475
```

And source code just for good measure :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
   <Document>
    <Placemark>
        <name>test</name>
            <Polygon>
                <extrude>1</extrude>
                <altitudeMode>irrelativeToGround</altitudeMode>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            10.416666666667,40.375 10.583333333333,40.891666666667 10.25,40.891666666667 10.25,40.058333333333 10.583333333333,40.058333333333
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>test</name>
            <Polygon>
                <extrude>1</extrude>
                <altitudeMode>irrelativeToGround</altitudeMode>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            10.25,40.391666666667 10.145833333333,40.491666666667 10.4,40.575 10.504166666667,40.475
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
</Document>
```

I've also tried adding `"header('Content-type: application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml');"` turning it into a KML file but to no effect, the `"new_source.once('change', function(){})"` event doesn't update the polygons no matter how many polygons i add or how many coordinates I change, and I can't figure out why.

EDIT: Now this is embarrassing, seems all i had to do was to remove

```
if (polygons!== undefined)
        polygons.setVisible(false);
```

And insert the `"testpolygons();"` line into a setInterval.

Only took me a week and a half, to figure out.

Now the only thing is that even if source does not change is still calls the function, but otherwise it works as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to call map.redraw() ?

Comment: Now i have but it doesn't seem to work either, but thanks for the try.